# code not working google chrome

Tags: jquery, getelementbyid

input button

```
<input type="submit" value="Gönder" onclick="tikla()" id="button-blue" />
```

tikla function

```
<script>
    function tikla() {
        document.getElementById("Button1").click()
    }
</script>
```

button1

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Style="visibility: hidden" Width="0px" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

problem solved

```
 <input type="submit" value="Gönder" onclick="tikla()" id="button-blue" />
```

changed

```
 <input type="button" value="Gönder" onclick="tikla()" id="button-blue" />
```

Comment: Try `$("#Button1").trigger('click');` Bdw you have `submit button` and if you have it inside `form` then it will post the `form` and you won't see your `Button1`'s action unless you prevent it..

Comment: function tikla() {

            $("#Button1").trigger('click');

        }
not working

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `ClientIDMode="Static"` to your `Button1` ASP tag:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Style="visibility: hidden" Width="0px" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

The reason for this is that ASP generates an ID based on the ID you've fed it in the `ID` attribute, but the generated ID will not match this exactly. Setting `ClientIDMode` to Static will mean that the ID you input into the ASP attribute will be the one that's output to the HTML.